# Sendgrid Whitelabel email links not working

Tags: sendgrid, email

I've set up my Sendgrid account to use whitelabels for the domain and email links. This service is being used for a discourse forum.

I can see the SPF Sender permits sendgrid to send on behalf of my domain but the links are pointing to `xxxx.ct.sendgrid.net` instead of `mail.mydomain` as I expect.

All the CNAME records are marked as valid and default in Sendgrid's control panel and I can verify they exist when I query the CNAME records.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the update last year, Domain Whitelabels and Links Whitelabels cannot be on the same subdomain anymore. You'll want to review your Whitelabels, make sure none of them have Yellow Warning tags on them. If they do, contact SG Support for assistance.
Assuming they don't, just rerun the Validation on each of them to make sure your recodes are good. If they are, everything should be working out properly.